# Getting error in running angular 7 project locally

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I Have an angular 7 project on Github, trying to run locally I am getting several errors, 
did all the efforts, but did not get any solution,

please visit the image for more clearance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think as per error message in your angular 7 project have a dependency of bootstrap. when your are configure this application locally then bootstrap configuration not found so such errors occours.

you need to check below steps:
1) confirm package.json contains dependencies for bootstrap
2) if you using bootstrap then it requires its dependecies like jquery & proper.js so install it
3) add below lines to "angular.js" file in Build Array Add - > Styles

```
["./node_module/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"]
```

And in Script Array Add - >

```
["./node_module/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "./node_module/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
```

I think after following above step your problem get solved.